# ¿Cómo pongo a funcionar la comparación entre dos variables? (Batch - if / else)

Tags: batch

Estuve trabajando recientemente en un updater hecho en **batch** que trabaja con una versión de Windows del wget. Pero lo que viene al caso es que estoy teniendo el problema con una línea en específico.

Hay una carpeta llamada `Updater` donde hay dos carpetas, una es la del wget (llamada *"wget"*) y la otra es una denominada `Tracker` de la que hay un archivo, y debo comparar lo que se encuentra en ese archivo con otro que se descarga vía wget como un "comprobador de versión actual"

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (cuever.txt) do (set interver=%%x)

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (Updater\Tracker\cuever.txt) do (set urver=%%x)

if %interver% == %urver% ( goto updatetime ) else ( goto uptodate )
```

En los comandos `for` no tengo ningún problema, pero los agrego para que se entienda cómo va la línea de código. Necesito saber cómo hacer funcionar la comparación entre variables, ya que siempre se salta al menú `:uptodate` en vez de ir a `:updatetime`. Por más que fuerzo a que ambos archivos sean diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con este código:

```
if %interver% == %urver% goto updatetime
if NOT %interver% == %urver% goto uptodate
```

Answer (score 1):

Al inicio del programa:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

la ruta prueba poniendola completa y dentro de comillas dobles:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("C:\turuta...\cuever.txt") do (set 
interver=%%x)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("C:\turuta...\Updater\Tracker\cuever.txt") do (set urver=%%x)
```

Si ya validaste que informacion te esta asignando en las variables que tienes (para eso puedes utilizar un "echo" y en lugar de "%" utiliza "!"

```
echo !interver!
echo !urver!
pause
```

si las variables te escriben algo en pantalla, entonces puedes pasar al siguiente punto... si no, algo tienes mal en la informacion que estas jalando.

en la comparacion de variables prueba con el if multilinea y a la funcion que vas a llamar agregale do puntos: ":" como se muestra en seguida:

```
if !interver!==!urver! ( 
  goto :updatetime
) else (
  goto :uptodate 
)
```

en resumen... el codigo quedaria asi:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:inicio
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("C:\turuta...\cuever.txt") do (set interver=%%x)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("C:\turuta...\Updater\Tracker\cuever.txt") do (set urver=%%x)
REM ver info de variables
echo !interver!
echo !urver!
pause
if !interver!==!urver! ( 
  goto :updatetime
) else (
  goto :uptodate 
)
:updatetime
 ...secuencia de comandos
goto :inicio
:uptodate
 ...secuencia de comandos
goto :inicio
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta poniendo comillas a las variables.

```
"%interver%" == "%urver%"
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar por que debe usar comillas?